# how to use append() after() before() when adding parent tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I added multiple `<option>` for `#inputPanel`,then try to set `<select>`

```
for (i = 0 ;i < data.length;i++){
    $('#inputPanel').append(`<option>${data[i]['name']}</option>`);
}

$('#inputPanel').after("</select>");
$('#inputPanel').before("<select>");
console.log($('#inputPanel').html()); // there is not select???
```

`select` tag is not added to `DOM`.

How can I make this??

Answer (score 4):

An `<option>` doesn't make sense if it's not a child of a `<select>`. Create the `<select>` first.

```js
const data = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }];
const select = $('<select>').appendTo('#inputPanel');
for (const { name } of data) {
  $('<option>')
    .text(name) // .text is safer than direct interpolation
    .appendTo(select);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputPanel"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this looks very neat and cool. It works well